# Duda modulo email y smtp en python3

Tags: python-3.x

Cuando ejecuto mi codigo, (el cual consiste en enviar un texto y a su vez una imagen adjunta) la imagen que recibo en mi correo no se puede abrir, dice que el fichero esta vacio, no se que hacer, lo he intentado todo.

Por otra parte me gustaria que me aclaracen unas dudas respecto al metodo add_header() del modulo email.mime.image de la clase MIMEImage(), no entiendo el porque de estos argumentos -> 'Content-Disposition','attachment',filename = "testing.jpg".

Otra cosa es el metodo ehlo() del moudlo smtp, he visto que se usa mucho antes y despues del metodo starttls(), porque?, cual es el cometido de este metodo?. Si no estoy mal el metodo starttls() encripta los datos que hallan despues de su llamado.

Por ultimo siempre que veo dodumentacion me doy cuenta que para enviar varias cosas usan MIMEMultipart, si solo es texto pues solo se usa MIMEText, pero si solo es una imagen es ahi el disucrso jaja. Para enviar una imagen hacen uso de MIMEMultipart, ¿acaso no es posible hacerlo solo con MIMEImage?, de ser cierto, ¿como se hace?.

Espero pronta ayuda

Muchas gracias.

```
import smtplib
import webbrowser as wb 
from getpass import getpass as spectre
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

class Data():
    def __init__(self,correo_in,correo_out,mensaje,password):
        self.correo_in = correo_in
        self.correo_out = correo_out
        self.password = password
        self.mensaje = mensaje

class Service():
    def __init__(self):
        self.menu()

    def menu(self):
        while True:
            question = input("\nYa permitiste el acceso de apps menos seguras?\n\n[Y/N] >>> ").upper()
            if question == 'Y':
                pass
            elif question == 'N':
                wb.open('https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps')
            else:
                print("Error, vuelve a intentarlo.")
            break

        cor_in = input("\nIngresa tu correo\n\n>>> ")
        cor_out = input("\nIngresa el correo del remitente\n\n>>> ")
        mss = input("\nIngresa el mensaje\n\n>>> ")
        pasw = spectre("\nIngresa tu contraseña\n\n>>> ")
        client = Data(cor_in,cor_out,mss,pasw)

        try:
            self.send_email(client)
        except Exception as error:
            print(type(error).__name__)

    def send_email(self,client):

        #server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')

        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com',587)
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.ehlo()
        server.login(client.correo_in,client.password)

        #msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg = MIMEMultipart()

        msg['From'] = client.correo_in
        msg['To'] = client.correo_out
        msg['Subject'] = "Ahora si tiene asunto xd"

        msg.attach(MIMEText(client.mensaje,'plain'))

        with open("testing.jpg",'rb') as file:
            contenido = MIMEImage(file.read(),_subtype = 'jpg')

        contenido.add_header('Content-Disposition','attachment',filename = "testing.jpg")
        msg.attach(contenido)

        server.sendmail(client.correo_in,client.correo_out,msg.as_string())
        server.quit()
        print("\nThe message has been sent successfully.")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    init = Service()
```

Answer (score 0):

Te comparto una forma de mandar imagenes por mail,
desconozco bien el funcionamiento de `smtplib`, espero que pueda servirte el ejemplo.
Lo que hago es guardar en una lista `imagenes`, los nombres de las imagenes, y en `directorio`, guardo la ubicación.(todas las imagenes se encuentran en el mismo directorio).

Por otra parte, al pasarle `'Content-Disposition'`, estás diciendo que muestre el nombre del adjunto, que en tu caso sería "testing.jpg". Sólo te puedo ayudar con eso.

```
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import smtplib

def enviarMail(aux_reporte,aux_imagenes,aux_directorio,aux_destinatarios):


    user = 'usuario'
    password = 'contraseña'
    # Mensaje
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = " Soy yo "
    msg['Subject'] = f'** Reporte de :  {aux_reporte} **'

    for imgs in aux_imagenes:
        try:
            part = MIMEApplication(open(aux_directorio+f"/{imgs}" ,"rb").read())
            part.add_header('Content-Disposition', 'attachment', filename = imgs)
        except:
            part = MIMEText(" No se encuentran imagenes ")
        msg.attach(part)

    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    server.starttls()

    server.login(user,password)
    server.sendmail(user, aux_destinatarios, msg.as_string())
    server.quit()

#nombre de las imagenes
imagenes = ['photo1','photo2','photo3']
directorio = "directorio de las imagenes"

destinatarios = 'usuario1@gmail.com','usuario2@gmail.com'
enviarMail("Mi Reporte",imagenes,directorio,destinarios)
```